# Python How do i fix Tkinter window crashing due to sleep function

Tags: python, tkinter, time

I have a problem with my Tkinter window crashing due to the usage of the 'sleep' function in the code below.
The programm in the background works just fine, even if the window crashed a long time ago.

How can I use functions like time.time to ensure that I don't make queries to the API too frequently rather than making a blocking call to time.sleep.
In other words, once I follow a list of new users, how do I prevent the program from making another request in the next 30 seconds?

```
        def follow_users(self,users_list):
            api = self.api
            api.login()
            api.getSelfUsersFollowing()
            result = api.LastJson
            for user in result['users']:
                following_users.append(user['pk'])
            for user in users_list:
                if not user['pk'] in following_users:
                    print('Following @' + user['username'])
                    api.follow(user['pk'])
                    # set this really long to avoid from suspension
                    sleep(30)
                else:
                    print('Already following @' + user['username'])
                    sleep(15)

        def unfollow_users(self):
            api = self.api
            api.login()
            api.getSelfUserFollowers()
            result = api.LastJson
            for user in result['users']:
            follower_users.append({'pk':user['pk'],     'username':user['username']})

            api.getSelfUsersFollowing()
            result = api.LastJson
            for user in result['users']:
          following_users.append({'pk':user['pk'],'username':user['username']})
           for user in following_users:
            if not user['pk'] in follower_users:
                print('Unfollowing @' + user['username'])
                api.unfollow(user['pk'])
                sleep(20)
                # set this really long to avoid from suspension
```

Comment: This isn't a question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: Thanks for editing, but now this is an exact duplicate of [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65614196/354577). That's not what we were asking you to do. Please ask a clear, focused, on-topic (see the [help/on-topic]) question. _Specifically_, what do you mean by 'work around the "sleep" funktion in the code to prevent the Tkinter window from crashing'? I doubt we need all of this code. A [mcve] would be much better.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by writing a function that follows a single user, and nothing more. It doesn't need to loop over a list or sleep or anything like that, it should just follow that one user.

For example:

```
def follow_user(self, user):
    ... code to follow this user ...
```

Next, define a function that pulls one user off of a list, calls the `follow_user` function, and then re-schedules itself to run again after a timeout.

The following example assumes there's a global variable named `root` which represents the root window, but you can use any widget you want. It also assumes that the class maintains a list of users to be followed in an instance variable named `self.users`.

```
def follow_users(self):
    if self.users:
        user = self.users.pop()
        self.follow_user(user)
    root.after(30000, self.follow_users)
```

Then, once your program starts, call this function exactly once. It will call itself once every 30 seconds. If there is at least one user in `self.users` it will pull it from the list and follow the user. 30 seconds later it will do it again, and then again, and so on. You can update `self.users` whenever you want and that user will eventually get followed.